# Using Custom function in Sub routine. Look at each cell within range, apply custom function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that uses a function that users from stackoverflow have helped me learn (`ConvertDates`).

This is the code thus far:

```
Sub CopyTempToFinal()
    Worksheets("g_temp").Range("A:CU").Copy
    With Worksheets("g_final")
        .Range("A:CU").PasteSpecial 12
    End With
End Sub

Sub CovertCellsToDate()
    ActiveSheet.Name = "g_final"

    Dim LastRowRec As Long
    LastRowRec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("g_final").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRowRec, 98)).Cells
        If InStr(c, "/") > 0 Then c = CovertDates(c)
    Next
End Sub
```

After copying over from temp to final, I wanted to search the cells within the column range A:CU up to the last populated row, and then apply the `ConvertDates` function to them. I wanted to combine the above two sub routines.

The function tp be applied is:

```
Function ConvertDates(ValueDate As Range)
    Dim Dates() As String
    Dates = Split(ValueDate.Text, "/")
    ConvertDates = Dates(1) & "/" & Dates(0) & "/" & Dates(2)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, I apologize for the inconvenience. I will perform the indentations for user readability next time. Thank you for editing. Much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, you have a typo ("CovertDates") in your For loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues with your `CovertCellsToDate` sub. This should work:

```
Sub CovertCellsToDate()
    Dim c As Range
    ActiveSheet.Name = "g_final"

    Dim LastRowRec As Long
    LastRowRec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("g_final").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("g_final").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRowRec, 98)).Cells
        If InStr(c, "/") > 0 Then c = ConvertDates(c)
    Next
End Sub
```

1. As @TimWilliams mentioned ConvertDates() was misspelled
2. You need to `Dim c As Range`
3. Be careful in using `ActiveSheet`. If you need to use it, you need to make **sure** that g_sheet is the Active (currently selected) sheet- or else you will get an error. After renaming the worksheet, it is much better to consistently use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("g_final")`. I do not see that you are changing the active sheet anywhere after copying the temp sheet, so it's possible your problems could be due to ActiveSheet.

Comment: I want to copy every on the temp sheet to the final sheet, but I want the dates that are not consistently in the right format to be converted to proper and consistent format using CovertDates() function above. So after copying everything over, any cell which contains a date, apply the ConvertDates() function. I had trouble calling the custom fuction within the macro as well.

Comment: What kind of trouble did you have with it? Were you getting an error?

Comment: Your `If InStr(c, "/") > 0` should work as long as (a) the cells that are not in the right format are always in the dd/mm/yyyy format and (b) there aren't any other fields that have the slash in them.